# send audio by formdata in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, audio

I am trying to send an audio file with the library [here](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-audio-recorder-player) and everything is fine, record, stop and play the audio, but when I try to send this audio file by formdata, the file breaks.

Here is my code:

```
formData.append("data[file_name]", {
  uri: this.state.uriAudio,
  name: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'test.mp4' : 'test.m4a',
  type: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'audio/mp4' : 'audio/m4a',
})
```

but when the file arrives, the audio file format changes and these are the results I get:

```
"file": {
           "url": "http://.......",
           "name": "test.m4a",
           "content_type": "audio/x-m4a",
           "upload_date": "Dec  5, 2018",
           "size": "3 MB"
       }
```

When I try to play the audio, the format is broken.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution but with another library, [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) and [react-native-audio](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio)

in the project the way to import is:

```
import {AudioRecorder, AudioUtils} from 'react-native-audio';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

formData.append("data[file_name]", {
      uri: Platform.OS == 'android' ? 'file://' + this.state.uriAudio:this.state.uriAudio,
      name: 'test.aac',
      type: 'audio/aac'
    })
```

this way has worked for me, I hope you help them

Answer (score 0):

I use this library [react-native-audio-recorder-player](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-audio-recorder-player)

You can find how to record and play in doc,

But for example;

```
  const _onRecord = async () => {
    const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder();
    setRecordStatus(true); // I use for control the media player
    audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
      setRecordDetail({
        recordSecs: e.current_position,
        recordTime: audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.current_position)),
      });
    });
  };

  const _onStop = async () => {
    const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
    setRecordStatus(false);
    setRecordingPath(result); // My record uri
    audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
    setRecordDetail({
      ...recordDetail,
      recordSecs: 0,
    });
    console.log(result);
  };
```

Your record should be like;

```
  formData.append('file', {
    uri:
      Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? record
        : record.replace('file://', ''),
    name: 'test.mp4',
    type: 'audio/mp4',
  });
```